# Capture a number in a string

Tags: mysql

I store a serialized table in a Mysql column. The data looks like this:

a:2:{i:116;s:1:"4";i:**113**;s:1:"6";}

I'm trying to extract the number that's always placed before `;s:1:"6";`
In the example above, the number would be 113.

I'm running Mysql 5.7, so I don't have access to new regex functions. It would have been nice to access PREG_CAPTURE and just write

```
PREG_CAPTURE(\'i:([0-9]+);s:1:"6";\', mycolumn, 1)
```

But I can't use PREG_CAPTURE and I'm stuck. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use substring_index.
Try this

> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( field1, ';s:1:"6";',1 )

Comment: It would return the string before `;s:1:"6";` In my example, that would be `a:2:{i:116;s:1:"4";i:113` How to extract the number **113** then?

Comment: Use regex s:1:"+[0-9]" as mentioned in the link https://www.regextester.com/?fam=103604

Comment: Regex for capturing are not part of mysql < 8